# PUT method in jersey

Tags: jersey

I am new to Restful webservice. When I was going through the tutorials, I saw that PUT method can be used to create the resource. the creation means adding into the database or somewhere by implementing our own effort? or will  Jersey take care of creating the resource its own? 
Sorry for asking silly questions.. I did not get the way what PUT is doing..

Thanks
Bhanu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jersey won't do anything except you tell it to. A PUT request semantically should create or update a ressource, so if you plan to create some entity, thats the HTTP method to use. Use `@PUT` to annotate your method and implement your functionality (as your tutorials tell you).

Comment: ok. I got that point. But where it is creating?Is that any database configuration we need to do?

Comment: That also depends on your requirements. After calling the annotated method, you can of course use something like JPA to persist the submitted data. This should be rather straigt forward if you have experience in that area.

Comment: int the tutorial it was mentioning some db4 which creates the files in temp.

Comment: As I said: you can do whatever you want with that input. Write to disc, send an email of it, store in the database etc.